# AS3 multiple (movieclip buttons) to animate one movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button, actionscript, movieclip

I am developing a desktop application. I am using ActionScript 3 via Adobe Animate CC. I designed the application, animated the GUI, and started coding. The main functions were successfully coded well, but I have added some additional features which are out of the scope of the application's original goals.  All of this just to link the application to a website and some other information, which made me totally crazy because I've spent too much time with very simple `if` statement LOGIC!

Anyway, I created a menu with three `MovieClip` buttons. These menu button clicks affect one `MovieClip` that has a white background that moves with each click. I need there to be one background to show the beautiful effect of `easeIn` and `easeOut` animation tweens when clicking each button.

**About** clicked
[image: when About button is clicked]

**Gallery** clicked
[image: when Gallery button is clicked]

**Contact** clicked
[image: when contact button is clicked]

To make it easy to understand, I recreated the code with a very simple ball and 3 buttons. If you click first button, the ball moves to the right above the 2nd button. Then the first button should be unclickable, unless another button is clicked. If the second button is clicked, then the ball would move to the right above the third button. Then the second button should be unclickable also, unless another button is clicked. The same thing goes for the third button.

[image: Ball Demonstration]

Now, if the first button is clicked again, the animation of the white background should not start from the default position when starting up the application!
It should animated back from its current position to the default position... and so on...

I replaced the white background with a ball for simplicity

This is very easy but I lost it with the `eventListeners`, `eventHandlers`, and `if` statements! :/

I also made this table which studies the cases:

[image: Clicking Possibilities]

I know my coding technique is not smart enough, but that is because *I HATE* using classes, packages, project folders... etc..

Even if the code runs too long & repeats, It would be better for me for simplicity, as programming is not my day-job!

Please, any help and quick response would be highly appreciated!

**Code:**

```
import flash.ui.Mouse;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

one.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, moveToSecondPos);
two.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, moveToThirdPos);
//three.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, moveToFirstPos);

var buttonState:Boolean;
one.buttonState = 0;
two.buttonState = 0;
//three.buttonState = 0;

function moveToSecondPos(event:MouseEvent){
    if(one.buttonState == 0){
    theBall.gotoAndPlay("go1");
    one.buttonState = 1;
    }
    else if(two.buttonState == 1){
    theBall.gotoAndPlay("backToOne");
//  two.buttonState = 0;
//  one.buttonState = 1;
    }
    else{
    //disable About Button
    one.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, moveToSecondPos);     
    }   
}

function moveToThirdPos(event:MouseEvent){
    if((two.buttonState == 0)&&(one.buttonState == 0)){
    theBall.gotoAndPlay("goProducts");
    two.buttonState = 1;
    }
    else if(one.buttonState == 1){
    theBall.gotoAndPlay("go2");
//  two.buttonState = 1;
//  one.buttonState = 1;
    }
    else{
    two.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, moveToThirdPos);      
    }
}

//function moveToFirstPos(event:MouseEvent){
//  if(three.buttonState == 0){
//  theBall.gotoAndPlay("go3");
//  three.buttonState = 1;
//  }
//  else{
//  three.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, moveToFirstPos);        
//  }
//}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you mentioned you wanted to have the

> white background should not start from the default position when starting up the application

For that, you'll need a [`ShareObject`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html) or comparable method of saving and loading data.

Secondly, It appears you may be trying to do some of this with Scenes and Timeline' frames.  I highly encourage you not to pursue that.

Below is a solution to the problems you mentioned.  Notice that without your project, I had to recreate the scene.  You can copy & paste the solution into a new scene and it will compile.

- To prevent buttons from being clicked, you can remove the event listener by calling [`myButton.removeEventListener("click")`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html#removeEventListener()).  Alternatively, you can simply stop the object from responding to mouse events by setting its [`mouseEnabled`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#mouseEnabled) property to false.
- To animate the box smoothly, you can use the built-in [Tween class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/transitions/Tween.html).  Alternatively, I'd direct you [Greensock's TweenLite](https://greensock.com/tweenlite-as).
- Because you appeared to want a series of labels to appear depending on the button clicked, I created an array which stores data specific to each button (`btns:Array`).  By using an organized structure, it's easier to write re-useable code which doesn't depend on explicit functions.  Note that there's only one `btnListener()` function which works for all of your buttons.

**Solution**

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.text.TextField;
import fl.motion.Color;
import fl.transitions.*;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;

// the list of buttons we want, along with the descriptions for each
var btns:Object = [
    {
        "label":"About",
        "desc":"Learn more about us",
        "btn":null
    },
    {
        "label":"Gallery",
        "desc":"See our photos",
        "btn":null
    },
    {
        "label":"Contact",
        "desc":"Write, call, or message",
        "btn":null
    }
];

var nav:Sprite; // our navigation bar of buttons
var whiteBox:Sprite; // the "ball" with the content text
// where we save the coordinates of the whiteBox between loads
var settings:Object = SharedObject.getLocal("foo");

init();
function init():void {
    // Create our navigation of three buttons

    // our container for buttons
    nav = new Sprite(); 

    // reference to the last button
    var last:Sprite = null; 

    // loop through the list of buttons
    for each (var entry:Object in btns) {
        // For each button, create a new button
        var btn:Sprite = createButton(entry.label);
        entry.btn = btn;
        nav.addChild(btn);

        // If there was a previous button, place this beside it.
        if (last != null) {
            btn.x = last.x + last.width + 1;
        }

        last = btn;
    }

    // Place the nav onscreen
    addChild(nav);
    nav.x = stage.stageWidth/2 - nav.width/2;
    nav.y = stage.stageHeight - nav.height*2;

    // Create the whitebox
    whiteBox = new Sprite();
    whiteBox.graphics.beginFill(0xFAFAFA);
    whiteBox.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 150, 50);
    whiteBox.graphics.endFill();

    var txt:TextField = new TextField();
    txt.name = "txt";
    txt.width = 150;
    whiteBox.addChild(txt);
    nav.addChild(whiteBox);

    // Load the settings from the last run of the program.
    if (settings.data.hasOwnProperty("x")) {
        whiteBox.x = settings.data.x;
        whiteBox.y = settings.data.y;
    } 
}

function createButton(label:String):Sprite {
    // Creates a simple button

    // Create the label
    var txt:TextField = new TextField();
    txt.text = label;

    // Create the background
    var btn:Sprite = new Sprite();
    btn.graphics.beginFill(0xA1A1A1);
    btn.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, txt.width + 60, txt.height + 30);
    btn.graphics.endFill();
    btn.addChild(txt);
    btn.name = label;
    txt.x = 30;
    txt.y = 15;

    // Hookup events
    btn.addEventListener("mouseOver", btnListener);
    btn.addEventListener("mouseOut", btnListener);
    btn.addEventListener("click", btnListener);

    return btn;
}

function btnListener(e:Event):void {
    var btn:Sprite = e.currentTarget as Sprite;
    var c:Color = new Color();
    var entry:Object;

    // Find our button in the list.
    for each (entry in btns) {
        if (entry.label == btn.name) {
            break;
        }
    }

    switch (e.type) {
        case "mouseOver":           
            if (btn.mouseEnabled) {
                c.setTint(0x0096ff, 0.5);
                btn.transform.colorTransform = c;
            }
            break;
        case "mouseOut":
            if (btn.mouseEnabled) {
                c.setTint(0x00, 0);
                btn.transform.colorTransform = c;
            }           
            break;
        case "click":
            // Set the text, and position of our whitebox
            whiteBox.getChildAt(0)["text"] = entry.desc;
            whiteBox.y = -whiteBox.height;

            var tween:Tween = new Tween(whiteBox, "x", Regular.easeOut, whiteBox.x, btn.x, 0.35, true);
            tween.addEventListener("motionFinish", saveState);

            for each (var v:Object in btns) {
                if (v.btn == btn) {
                    // make our button unclickable
                    btn.mouseEnabled = false;
                    c.setTint(0xFFFFFF, 0.5);
                    btn.transform.colorTransform = c;
                } else {
                    // Make the other buttons clickable;
                    v.btn.mouseEnabled = true;
                    c.setTint(0x00, 0);
                    v.btn.transform.colorTransform = c;
                }
            }
            break;
    }   
}

function saveState(e:Event):void {
    settings.data.x = whiteBox.x;
    settings.data.y = whiteBox.y;
    settings.flush();
}
```